# C# Destroy other game object inside coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I have a script attached to a gameobject with a trigger collider. I want every game object with tag scale to be destroyed on trigger enter. my problem is I want it to be destroyed only after X time. Im trying to use coroutine for that but I get an error. thanks in advance guys - this is my scrip:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "scale")
    {
        StartCoroutine(DestroyingScale());
    }

}



IEnumerable DestroyingScale()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: You coroutine has no knowledge of a variable called `other` since that only exists within `OnTriggerEnter` - you need to actually pass it as an argument to the coroutine

Comment: The error is inside the coroutine "The name 'other' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @UnholySheep And how do I do that my dear sir?

Comment: The same way you pass an argument to any other method... There's even an example in the official docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: And also, when I call for start coroutine its says "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable to 'string"

Comment: Oh, you didn't even create a coroutine. A coroutine has an `IEnumerator` return type, not `IEnumerable`

Comment: hahaha doh, Thanks man but still how can I pass the other to the coroutine?

Comment: I know coroutines are popular in Unity and their use of `IEnumerator` and `yield` creating a hot debate in the C# world, but if the past month is anything to go by, they should perhaps be _outlawed_. Numerous recent posts whereby **unguarded** `StartCoroutine` are spammed in either the `Update` or `OnTriggerEnter` methods leading to excessive coroutine sessions.  When you consider `Update` could be called as much as **60 times a second** or more, such code can be **hazardous**.   `StartCoroutine` may look innocent but I can't help but wonder it is as dangerous as `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: I'm not across if `OnTriggerEnter` is only called _once_ per collision but if you do use coroutines it is best to wrap them in a guard statement so that you don't fire them too frequently/unnecessarily.   e.g.  `if (other.gameObject.tag == "scale"  &&  !_isBusy) { _isBusy = true; StartCoroutine(...); }`.   Reset the flag when the coroutine completes.

Comment: @MickyD Wow man thanks for that, I've been using them quite a bit

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument(s) to the coroutine function.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "scale")
    {
        StartCoroutine(
            DestroyingScale(other.gameObject)
        );
    }
}

private IEnumerator DestroyingScale(GameObject scale)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    if (scale)
    {
        Destroy(scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love you @hijinxbassist

Comment: Just a follow up, how do I reset this whole thing so the next scale would also be destroyed after x time?

Comment: There is no "reset" required.  Each scale you hit will delay 5 seconds before being destroyed.

Comment: getting an error in my console tho, "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object." @hijinxbassist

Comment: check the stack trace of the exception in the console, see which call site it responsible for raising the exception.

Comment: @chanabanana _"I love you @hijinxbassist"_ - lol

Comment: I'm not across if `OnTriggerEnter` is only called _once_ per collision but if you do use coroutines it is best to wrap them in a guard statement so that you don't fire them too frequently/unnecessarily.   e.g.  `if (other.gameObject.tag == "scale"  &&  !_isBusy) { _isBusy = true; StartCoroutine(...); }`.   Reset the flag when the coroutine completes.   +1 regardless.    :)

Comment: That would have the potential for missing collisions though.  The delay is 5 seconds, even a 500ms delay could cause issues of missed collisions.  I think a better way is handling the coroutine on the target instance instead, then that instance knows its marked for destruction and not to start the routine again.